# PHP SQL sqlsrv SUM ... GROUP BY doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have QUERY like this:

```
$query2 = "
SELECT plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika, plb_Wyplata.wyp_ObciazeniePracodawcy, SUM(plb_Wyplata.wyp_StatGodzPrzepr) AS wyp_StatGodzPrzepr, YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac), MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac)
FROM plb_Wyplata 
    INNER JOIN plb_Umowa ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdUmowy = plb_Umowa.up_Id
    INNER JOIN plb_ListaPlac ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdListyPlac = plb_ListaPlac.lp_Id
WHERE (YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '$year') AND (MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '$month')
GROUP BY plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika
ORDER BY plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika";
```

and it gives bool.

Once I remove: SUM and ORDER BY query returnes proper values. Like this:

```
$query2 = "
SELECT plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika, plb_Wyplata.wyp_ObciazeniePracodawcy, plb_Wyplata.wyp_StatGodzPrzepr, YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac), MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac)
FROM plb_Wyplata 
    INNER JOIN plb_Umowa ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdUmowy = plb_Umowa.up_Id
    INNER JOIN plb_ListaPlac ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdListyPlac = plb_ListaPlac.lp_Id
WHERE (YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '$year') AND (MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '$month')
ORDER BY plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika";
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try the query directly in your database and see what it gives. BOOL probably means that your query failed.

Comment: Juts a hint, limiting data with year() and month() function will never use indexes. The proper way is to use >= and <= with the date value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have changed into this (directly in database)

```
SELECT plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika, plb_Wyplata.wyp_StatGodzPrzepr, YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac), MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac), SUM(plb_Wyplata.wyp_ObciazeniePracodawcy) as sumaWypl
FROM plb_Wyplata 
    INNER JOIN plb_Umowa ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdUmowy = plb_Umowa.up_Id
    INNER JOIN plb_ListaPlac ON plb_Wyplata.wyp_IdListyPlac = plb_ListaPlac.lp_Id
WHERE (YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '2020') AND (MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac) LIKE '7')
GROUP BY plb_Umowa.up_IdPracownika, plb_Wyplata.wyp_StatGodzPrzepr, YEAR(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac), MONTH(plb_ListaPlac.lp_Miesiac)
```

and it gives table, however SUM still doesn't work

```
1   8640    2020    7   8538,67
1   11040   2020    7   1707,68
2   8640    2020    7   6213,97
2   11040   2020    7   835,04
3   8640    2020    7   8979,44
3   11040   2020    7   1365,54
4   8640    2020    7   7174,34
4   11040   2020    7   1367,09
6   4320    2020    7   5784,02
8   8640    2020    7   9359,85
8   11040   2020    7   1534,02
9   1000    2020    7   698,11
10  8640    2020    7   7940,45
10  11040   2020    7   1707,68
11  8640    2020    7   8865,41
11  11040   2020    7   1707,66
12  8640    2020    7   9094,79
12  11040   2020    7   1367,07
```

It shoud be grouped by first column and las amount summed.

Comment: oooh sheeeit. The second column should be summed as well.